# Interpolate the gaps among NDVI values

Tags: software-recommendations, ndvi, values

I want to calculate the Crop Water Requirements and for this I need NDVI values for a period of time.

Because I have Sentinel 2 images and the temporal resolution is 5 days, I need also the values for NDVI for days when the satellite don't take the images.

Do you know a software that can interpolate/fill the gaps where I don't have NDVI values? I need to obtain just NDVI values for each day.

Comment: Do you need raster layers for each day or do you need just values? Please add this information editing your question

Comment: Sorry, I did not mention. I need just values for each days.

Comment: Since you need just NDVI values, you can use from excel to almost any statistical software. In terms of R processing, with `zoo()` and `na.approx()` you can do it easily. Are you working with ET0 to compute CWR?

Comment: I am working with ET0 to compute ETc and after these to compute CWR, GIWR and NIWR.

Comment: You can check the work of [UCLM](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5470494/) related to this topic and [Irrisat](https://irrisat-cloud.appspot.com), a very interesting tool mounted in GEE

Answer (score 4):

You can use R for this purpose. A really small example:

Given some rasters (where values are `(ndvi*100) + 100`):

```
library(raster)
library(zoo)
library(hydroTSM)

d1 <- raster('ndvi_2019-79.tif')
d2 <- raster('ndvi_2019-94.tif')
d3 <- raster('ndvi_2019-104.tif')

s <- stack(d1,d2,d3)

plot(s)
```

[image]

Create a date object with rasters names and an empty object with days in period:

```
dates <- names(s) # extract names
dates <- as.Date(dates, format = 'ndvi_%Y.%j')

dips <- dip(from = dates[1], to = dates[3])
zoo_ <- zoo(NA, order.by = dips)
idx <- which(dips %in% dates)
```

A function for fill gaps for those days:

```
fillGaps <- function(x){
  temp <- zoo_
  temp[idx] <- x
  na.approx(temp)
}

s2 <- calc(s, fillGaps)
```

And *voila*:

```
names(s2) <- dips
plot(s2)
```

[image]

---

A small area to see date differences (BTW, are Sentinel-2 ndvi product):

[image]